# Issue with authentication in MongoDB , when used with mongoVUE as admin UI

Tags: mongodb

I am using [mongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) as mongo admin UI.
My mongo server is running with authentication enabled
I have created one test db (say test_db) and one user(test_user) in that db. 
I have authorized test_db with test_user.
If i use mongo shell , than commands like "show db"  ,"show collections " in some db fails with authorization problem (this is fine and excepted).
But if use mongoVUE to login into mongo server using test_user. i am able to see all the db's. i can access them ,i can modify them.
Do anyone know what is happening here ?

Comment: the same database, with the same username & password, works in mongoVUE and doesn't work in mongo shell?

Comment: no..my question is different.one username and password gives access to all other datbases in mongoVUE (which is wrong). in shell it works fine as expected

Comment: aha, I see now. Only users from the admin database are allowed to see all databases. Can you confirm that mongoVUE does indeed use test_user and that it doesn't exist in the admin database?

Comment: test_user is there in admin database ,but this user doesnt have access to admin db. only admin user can access admin db.and mongoVUE is using test_user only.

Comment: ohhh..i got it now. it seems any user from admin database can access evreything. even if that account dosent have access to admin account also.

Comment: any user from the admin db can do anything (given that his account is not read only)

Comment: ok, you can mark the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users that are listed in the admin database have access to any other database, can do `show dbs` and `show collections`, without being explicitly added to any other database.